# Python import с верхних уровней

Tags: python, импорт

Предположим структура проекта выглядит примерно так:

```
/project
   /engine_
      reload.py
      changer.py
      main.py
   /exceptions_
      quality_extensions.py
      graph_extensions.py
   /validators_
      resp_validator.py
      some_validator.py
   /src
      1.png
      2.png
   /tests
```

Точка входа в папке engine_, main.py.
В валидаторах импортируются с папки exceptions_ некоторые нужные типы исключений.
В файлы в папке engine_ импортируются валидаторы с validators_, а также файлы из src.
Постоянно требуется импорт на уровень выше. Данную проблему я решаю костылём, как я считаю.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
```

Это хоть и работает всегда но приходится писать в каждом файле в который импортируются файлы из папок на уровень выше.
Питон по импорту вниз работает отлично, можно отталкиваться от этого, но структура проекта так себе будет.
Вопрос: есть ли альтернатива?

UPDATE:
Ну, это и вправду работает(раскидка везде файлов **init**.py). Проблема в том, что без init пакет не инициализируется. Чуть меньше действий по сравнению с методом в лоб с sys.path, но повторов не избежать. Буду копать дальше...

Comment: Сделайте весь project и все вложенные папки [пакетами](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/sistema-importa-python/fajl-paketa-init-py/) и используйте нормальное `from project.validators import some_validator` без издевательств над sys.path

Comment: Ну а запустить точку входа из пакета можно будет командой вроде `python -m project.engine.main` (зачем эти странные подчёркивания в конце имён?)

Comment: Так вроде с питон 3.3 версии все папки считаются пакетами, даже без __init__.py, или я ошибаюсь?